# JupyterLab vs virtualenv - cant find installed python package. Linux

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, centos, virtualenv, jupyter-lab

CentOS9. latest jupyter lab and python3.

I always thought that Jupyter is agnostic to the virtualenv and that it is the `ipykernel` which "knows" its environment

What I did:

- created virtual environment
- activated it
- installed kernel `ipython kernel install --user --name=pt`
- installed pytorch
- checked it with running python3

```
import torch
torch.__version__
```

- ran `jupyterlab --no-browser`
- opened browser and jupyter launcher, created new notebook with kernel `pt`
- tried torch got error:

```
import torch
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import torch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you install torch? what command are you using?

Comment: i found the problem. kernel should be installed using python from venv explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to install kernel differently:

```
pt/bin/python3 -m ipykernel install --name "pt"
```